# PdfSharp: Get PdfDocument from specified file path and name

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I am using pdfsharp in a .net application and am trying to open a pdf from a specified path and file name. However, when I try this:

```
PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(path, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
```

Where `path` is the filepath and name, it is appended to the path for my project's web folder. For example, if my path is `https:\site.net\files\thisfile.pdf`, it will search for `C:\Users\thisuser\Proj\ProjWeb\https:\site.net\files\thisfile.pdf` instead.

How can I get a `PdfDocument` using only the path and file name I have specified, without having this additional path being appended to it?

The solution must account for multiple filepaths as the value of `path` is based on other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load file from URL, while Pdfreader.Open only supports loading files locally or from a stream.

```
   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(path);
   Stream pdfstream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

   PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(pdfstream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
```

The above code will try to load the PDF from a remote url into Stream, then open the PDF from said stream. I haven't tested this, but according to this ( where the code was obtained ) https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2030, you might have to use MemoryStream in place of Stream.